# An issue with a body hair length vertex group

Tags: modeling, particles, hair, vertex-groups, curve-modifier

I can't regulate body hair length via vertex group in "Trim hair curves" modifier no matter which option I replace with that vertex group.
There was no such problem with similar group for a body hair density in "Interpolate hair curves" modifier.

[image]

The hair length without vertex group influence

[image]

The hair length vertex paint (White-0 Black-0.01 Red-1)

[image]

The hair length with a vertex group influence (The length is almost gone)

Blender3.5